# Map-Reduce not reducing as much as expected with complex keys and values

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

No matter how simple I make the compareTo of my complex key, I don't get expected results.  With the exception of if I use one key that is the same for every record, it will appropriately reduce to one record.  I've also witnessed that this happens only when I process the full load, if I break off a few of the records that didn't reduce and run it on a much smaller scale those records get combined.

The sum of the output records is correct, but there is duplication at the record level of items I would have expected to group together.  So where I would expect say 500 records summing up to 5,000, I end up with 1232 records summing up to 5,000 with obvious records that should have been reduced into one.

I've read about the problems with object references and complex keys and values, but I don't see anywhere that I have potential for that left.  To that end you will find places that I'm creating new objects that I probably don't need to, but I'm trying everything at this point and will dial it back once it is working.

I'm out of ideas on what to try or where and how to poke to figure this out.  Please help!

```
public static class Map extends
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IMSTranOut, IMSTranSums> {

    //private SimpleDateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddd");

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        SimpleDateFormat dtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyddd");

        IMSTranOut dbKey = new IMSTranOut();
        IMSTranSums sumVals = new IMSTranSums();

        String[] tokens = line.split(",", -1);

        dbKey.setLoadKey(-99);
        dbKey.setTranClassKey(-99);

        dbKey.setTransactionCode(tokens[0]);
        dbKey.setTransactionType(tokens[1]);
        dbKey.setNpaNxx(getNPA(dbKey.getTransactionCode()));

        try {
            dbKey.setTranDate(new Date(dtFormat.parse(tokens[2]).getTime()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }// 2

        dbKey.setTranHour(getTranHour(tokens[3]));

        try {
            dbKey.setStartDate(new Date(dtFormat.parse(tokens[4]).getTime()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }// 4

        dbKey.setStartHour(getTranHour(tokens[5]));

        try {
            dbKey.setStopDate(new Date(dtFormat.parse(tokens[6]).getTime()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }// 6

        dbKey.setStopHour(getTranHour(tokens[7]));

        sumVals.setTranCount(1);
        sumVals.setInputQTime(Double.parseDouble(tokens[8]));
        sumVals.setElapsedTime(Double.parseDouble(tokens[9]));
        sumVals.setCpuTime(Double.parseDouble(tokens[10]));

        context.write(dbKey, sumVals);
    }

}

public static class Reduce extends
        Reducer<IMSTranOut, IMSTranSums, IMSTranOut, IMSTranSums> {

    @Override
    public void reduce(IMSTranOut key, Iterable<IMSTranSums> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int tranCount = 0;
        double inputQ = 0;
        double elapsed = 0;
        double cpu = 0;

        for (IMSTranSums val : values) {
            tranCount += val.getTranCount();
            inputQ += val.getInputQTime();
            elapsed += val.getElapsedTime();
            cpu += val.getCpuTime();
        }

        IMSTranSums sumVals=new IMSTranSums();
        IMSTranOut dbKey=new IMSTranOut();

        sumVals.setCpuTime(inputQ);
        sumVals.setElapsedTime(elapsed);
        sumVals.setInputQTime(cpu);
        sumVals.setTranCount(tranCount);

        dbKey.setLoadKey(key.getLoadKey());
        dbKey.setTranClassKey(key.getTranClassKey());
        dbKey.setNpaNxx(key.getNpaNxx());
        dbKey.setTransactionCode(key.getTransactionCode());
        dbKey.setTransactionType(key.getTransactionType());
        dbKey.setTranDate(key.getTranDate());
        dbKey.setTranHour(key.getTranHour());
        dbKey.setStartDate(key.getStartDate());
        dbKey.setStartHour(key.getStartHour());
        dbKey.setStopDate(key.getStopDate());
        dbKey.setStopHour(key.getStopHour());

        dbKey.setInputQTime(inputQ);
        dbKey.setElapsedTime(elapsed);
        dbKey.setCpuTime(cpu);
        dbKey.setTranCount(tranCount);

        context.write(dbKey, sumVals);
    }
}
```

Here is the implementation of the DBWritable class:

```
public class IMSTranOut implements DBWritable,
    WritableComparable<IMSTranOut> {

private int loadKey;
private int tranClassKey;
private String npaNxx;
private String transactionCode;
private String transactionType;
private Date tranDate;
private double tranHour;
private Date startDate;
private double startHour;
private Date stopDate;
private double stopHour;
private double inputQTime;
private double elapsedTime;
private double cpuTime;
private int tranCount;

public void readFields(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    setLoadKey(rs.getInt("LOAD_KEY"));
    setTranClassKey(rs.getInt("TRAN_CLASS_KEY"));
    setNpaNxx(rs.getString("NPA_NXX"));
    setTransactionCode(rs.getString("TRANSACTION_CODE"));
    setTransactionType(rs.getString("TRANSACTION_TYPE"));
    setTranDate(rs.getDate("TRAN_DATE"));
    setTranHour(rs.getInt("TRAN_HOUR"));
    setStartDate(rs.getDate("START_DATE"));
    setStartHour(rs.getInt("START_HOUR"));
    setStopDate(rs.getDate("STOP_DATE"));
    setStopHour(rs.getInt("STOP_HOUR"));
    setInputQTime(rs.getInt("INPUT_Q_TIME"));
    setElapsedTime(rs.getInt("ELAPSED_TIME"));
    setCpuTime(rs.getInt("CPU_TIME"));
    setTranCount(rs.getInt("TRAN_COUNT"));
}

public void write(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
    ps.setInt(1, loadKey);
    ps.setInt(2, tranClassKey);
    ps.setString(3, npaNxx);
    ps.setString(4, transactionCode);
    ps.setString(5, transactionType);
    ps.setDate(6, tranDate);
    ps.setDouble(7, tranHour);
    ps.setDate(8, startDate);
    ps.setDouble(9, startHour);
    ps.setDate(10, stopDate);
    ps.setDouble(11, stopHour);
    ps.setDouble(12, inputQTime);
    ps.setDouble(13, elapsedTime);
    ps.setDouble(14, cpuTime);
    ps.setInt(15, tranCount);
}

public int getLoadKey() {
    return loadKey;
}

public void setLoadKey(int loadKey) {
    this.loadKey = loadKey;
}

public int getTranClassKey() {
    return tranClassKey;
}

public void setTranClassKey(int tranClassKey) {
    this.tranClassKey = tranClassKey;
}

public String getNpaNxx() {
    return npaNxx;
}

public void setNpaNxx(String npaNxx) {
    this.npaNxx = new String(npaNxx);
}

public String getTransactionCode() {
    return transactionCode;
}

public void setTransactionCode(String transactionCode) {
    this.transactionCode = new String(transactionCode);
}

public String getTransactionType() {
    return transactionType;
}

public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
    this.transactionType = new String(transactionType);
}

public Date getTranDate() {
    return tranDate;
}

public void setTranDate(Date tranDate) {
    this.tranDate = new Date(tranDate.getTime());
}

public double getTranHour() {
    return tranHour;
}

public void setTranHour(double tranHour) {
    this.tranHour = tranHour;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
}

public double getStartHour() {
    return startHour;
}

public void setStartHour(double startHour) {
    this.startHour = startHour;
}

public Date getStopDate() {
    return stopDate;
}

public void setStopDate(Date stopDate) {
    this.stopDate = new Date(stopDate.getTime());
}

public double getStopHour() {
    return stopHour;
}

public void setStopHour(double stopHour) {
    this.stopHour = stopHour;
}

public double getInputQTime() {
    return inputQTime;
}

public void setInputQTime(double inputQTime) {
    this.inputQTime = inputQTime;
}

public double getElapsedTime() {
    return elapsedTime;
}

public void setElapsedTime(double elapsedTime) {
    this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
}

public double getCpuTime() {
    return cpuTime;
}

public void setCpuTime(double cpuTime) {
    this.cpuTime = cpuTime;
}

public int getTranCount() {
    return tranCount;
}

public void setTranCount(int tranCount) {
    this.tranCount = tranCount;
}

public void readFields(DataInput input) throws IOException {
    setNpaNxx(input.readUTF());
    setTransactionCode(input.readUTF());
    setTransactionType(input.readUTF());
    setTranDate(new Date(input.readLong()));
    setStartDate(new Date(input.readLong()));
    setStopDate(new Date(input.readLong()));
    setLoadKey(input.readInt());
    setTranClassKey(input.readInt());
    setTranHour(input.readDouble());
    setStartHour(input.readDouble());
    setStopHour(input.readDouble());
    setInputQTime(input.readDouble());
    setElapsedTime(input.readDouble());
    setCpuTime(input.readDouble());
    setTranCount(input.readInt());
}

public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException {
    output.writeUTF(npaNxx);
    output.writeUTF(transactionCode);
    output.writeUTF(transactionType);
    output.writeLong(tranDate.getTime());
    output.writeLong(startDate.getTime());
    output.writeLong(stopDate.getTime());
    output.writeInt(loadKey);
    output.writeInt(tranClassKey);
    output.writeDouble(tranHour);
    output.writeDouble(startHour);
    output.writeDouble(stopHour);
    output.writeDouble(inputQTime);
    output.writeDouble(elapsedTime);
    output.writeDouble(cpuTime);
    output.writeInt(tranCount);
}

public int compareTo(IMSTranOut o) {

    return (Integer.compare(loadKey, o.getLoadKey()) == 0
            && Integer.compare(tranClassKey, o.getTranClassKey()) == 0
            && npaNxx.compareTo(o.getNpaNxx()) == 0
            && transactionCode.compareTo(o.getTransactionCode()) == 0
            && (transactionType.compareTo(o.getTransactionType()) == 0)
            && tranDate.compareTo(o.getTranDate()) == 0
            && Double.compare(tranHour, o.getTranHour()) == 0
            && startDate.compareTo(o.getStartDate()) == 0
            && Double.compare(startHour, o.getStartHour()) == 0
            && stopDate.compareTo(o.getStopDate()) == 0 
            && Double.compare(stopHour, o.getStopHour()) == 0) ? 0 : 1;

}
}
```

Implementation of the Writable class for the complex values:

```
public class IMSTranSums
 implements Writable{


        private double inputQTime;
        private double elapsedTime;
        private double cpuTime;
        private int tranCount;

        public double getInputQTime() {
            return inputQTime;
        }
        public void setInputQTime(double inputQTime) {
            this.inputQTime = inputQTime;
        }
        public double getElapsedTime() {
            return elapsedTime;
        }
        public void setElapsedTime(double elapsedTime) {
            this.elapsedTime = elapsedTime;
        }
        public double getCpuTime() {
            return cpuTime;
        }
        public void setCpuTime(double cpuTime) {
            this.cpuTime = cpuTime;
        }
        public int getTranCount() {
            return tranCount;
        }
        public void setTranCount(int tranCount) {
            this.tranCount = tranCount;
        }

        public void write(DataOutput output) throws IOException {
            output.writeDouble(inputQTime);
            output.writeDouble(elapsedTime);
            output.writeDouble(cpuTime);
            output.writeInt(tranCount);
        }
        public void readFields(DataInput input) throws IOException {
            inputQTime=input.readDouble();
            elapsedTime=input.readDouble();
            cpuTime=input.readDouble();
            tranCount=input.readInt();

        }
}
```

Comment: Your `compareTo` is flawed, it will totally fail the sort algorithm, because you don't order things at all. Did you ever thought of using a `CompareToBuilder` from commons or a `ComparisonChain` from guava?

Comment: So obvious!  Thank you!  I misunderstood the usage of the compareTo and was thinking of it as an equality check.  Working through the solution now, will report back.

Comment: It worked like a charm!  Thanks again.  How do I credit you with the solution?

Comment: Will add this as an answer that you can accept, sorry for the comment jazz :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `compareTo` is flawed, it will totally fail the sort algorithm, because you seem to break transivity in your ordering.

I would recommend you to use a `CompareToBuilder` from Apache Commons or a `ComparisonChain` from Guava to make your comparisons much more readable (and correct!).